# Shared folder not accessible

Tags: windows, dns, permissions

I and another co-worker have run into a problem where a shared folder is not accessible. Error "Open Folder - \server\share is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource[...]"

I know I have permission because I've always been able to access the folder, plus I still can from other computers. Same for my co-worker (though the folder he is accessing is different than the folder I am accessing). I'm the file server administrator, so I'm the one who would know if changes to permissions had been made - which seems irrelevant considering I can still access the shared folder from another computer.

The only changes that have been made that could be related would be that I reimaged my computer with Windows 10 rather than 7 recently, and that the file server was migrated to different hardware. If it were the hardware, I would think we'd have way more complaints about issues rather than just me and my co-worker. Plus, it's not every computer that has issues.

- Server actual name: server123
- Server actual FQDN: server123.domain.com
- Alias: server
- Alias FQDN: server.domain.com

It works when I use the server actual name/FQDN and when I use the alias FQDN. It also works when I use the IP. It just does not work when I use the unqualified alias.

Why am I unable to access the server using the unqualified alias?

Comment: if you `nslookup servername` does it respond with the new or old server IP? if its the old one, ensure that the DNS server has been updated on the change, perhaps by logging into the server and running `ipconfig /registerdns` as admin. That should update DNS to use the new IP.

Comment: It responds with the new server.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, your "Search Domain" settings for DNS suffixes are off.

In windows, to use shortname resolution (`ex1` instead of `ex1.example.com`), you must do one of two things:

1) set the system "Primary DNS Suffix". Hit Win+Break to open the System.cpl, and click the link button "Change Settings" in the section "Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings". Click the button "Change" and check the "Full Computer Name" setting. The DNS suffix on this name must be the same as the suffix for the servers FQDN. you can click "More" to set the system Primary DNS Suffix. If the server and client should not have the same suffix, then you should use option 2 below instead.

2) Set the NIC to use a Connection Specific DNS Suffix: In Control Panel -> "Network and Sharing Center", click "Change Adapter Settings" -> "Properties" -> "Interet Protocol v4" -> "Advanced" -> "DNS". Set "Append these DNS Suffixes", and put the DNS suffix for the servers FQDN in the box. 
Alternately, if you are a person working remotely over VPN, using a VPN virtual NIC, you can set the "DNS Suffix for this Connection".

Once your suffixes are set, you should be able to access the server by shortname, IP, or FQDN.

Comment: 1) The DNS suffix is the same as the suffix for the FQDN. 2) The DNS suffix is in the list to be appended already and is being used as the suffix for the connection. Still not working.

Comment: are you certain that the Windows name for the box is identical to the DNS shortname?

Comment: I am using an alias which is pointing to the server.

Comment: CNAME properties: alias name = server; fqdn = server.domain.com; fqdn for target host = server123.domain.com

Comment: It works when I use the actual name of the server rather than the alias.

Comment: so it works for A records, but fails for CNAMES? That kind of implies it may be performing the lookup from SMB, WINS, AVAHI, or Host file, rather than DNS. Have you confirmed that  the DNS settings for the box are identical to a working boxes DNS config?